# Подключение к lxc извне

Tags: http, debian, ssh, lxc

Настроил виртуалку ***lxc***. она работает, но как к ней подключится извне, по ssh или http? Делал по [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/271537/) инструкции. Система - Debian 8

Answer (score 1):

В указанной статье настраивается программный сетевой мост. Если вы корректно следовали действиям в статье, то виртуалка будет доступна по адресу, указанному в конфиге директивой `lxc.network.ipv4`.

ssh, http - не имеет значения, это L2 мост. Что в контейнере будет запущено и слушать сеть - те сервисы и будут доступны при обращениях к этому сетевому адресу.

Если же адрес вдруг не проявляет признаков жизни - то начать стоит со входа через `lxc-console` на виртуальную консоль контейнера и разбираться как с обычной linux-машинкой.

Comment: не совсем понял. например, сейчас основной сервер доступен по адресу 213.239.197.100. виртуалка имеет ip 192.168.0.77. к основному серверу я подключаюсь ***ssh -p 22 root@213.239.197.100***, а как мне подключится к виртуалке?

Comment: В таком случае опишите в вопросе все ваши отклонения от статьи. Что у вас в /etc/networks/interfaces на хост-системе, какие параметры сети заданы в конфиге lxc. И если вам нужен маршрутизируемый адрес для виртуалки, то какие адреса и подсети вам предоставил хостер.

Comment: все делал как в статье, только вместо адреса 192.168.0.11 подставил 192.168.0.77. По поводу подсетей - не знаю, как это можно посмотреть?

Comment: я посмотрел у хостера - я могу себе добавить как еще 1 IP так и еще одну подсеть. что мне нужно для моего случая?